# Can same application use for Huawei AppGallery without any changes?

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services

We received news from Google, that play store will no longer sho win Huawei.

Huawei has come up with another store called [AppGallery](https://huaweimobileservices.com/appgallery/) . The question is, can same apk upload to Huawei AppGallery and the other still active in Play Store ?

Comment: I think that will be possible, because an app will be used by different manufacturer devices right, so definitely it'll be possible

Comment: yeah, no problem, however, I advise to change the package name and AdMob id's to avoid any problem in future.

Comment: Huawei has its own in-app-purchase and ad sdk. I'm wondering if it will be necessary to use those in the future or if everything from google will still be sufficient. Does anyone have experience on that?

Comment: Hi @HelmiB Did you uploaded the same apk to AppGallery? If yes then do you wanna share any challenges?

Comment: Any update on this @HelmiB or @Mubarak? Do you guys uploaded to the AppGallery? Did you used the same package name and signing certificates? What about Google Admob or Firebase analytics? Isn't againts Google's terms and conditions to publish to the AppGallery? I don't want to get banned from Google Play Dev and/or from Admob.

Answer (score 3):

An annoying challenge arises on devices where both Play Store and Huawei AppGallery are installed. I distribute the same app with the same signature, but different mechanisms for purchasing access to premium functionality. If a user has installed the app from Play Store, and has acquired an in-app purchase, unfortunately the AppGallery updates the app also for this user, thus making him loose the purchase.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to upload the same APK file to both Google Play Store and HUAWEI AppGallery. But if your app uses GMS features like Google Sign-In or Firebase Cloud Messaging, it won't work well on the devices that don't have GMS, like Mate 30, P40, and any other new devices. Huawei app reviewers won't set it visible on HUAWEI AppGallery.
It's recommended that you use GMS if a device supports GMS; otherwise, use HMS (Huawei Mobile Services).

Please refer to the following links:

- To check [whether GMS is available](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)).
- [HMS Overview](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms)

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolutely the same *.apk (not *.aab).
The only problem (at least for us) is the absence google services =( So if you use pushes or remote config or smt like this it might be a problem. 
When it comes to firebase you can check services which require google services [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android#google-play-service-requirement)